# SSRS 2008 rendering of HTML markup (does not allow .xml links)

Tags: ssrs-2008, outlook-2007, infopath-2007

I am trying to create links to infopath forms stored in sharepoint.  This is MOSS 3 so they are not web based forms.  If I create a link through HTML markup within a placeholder it renders fine until I make it a .xml extension.  I'm using HTML markup because they need to display in Outlook 2007 too.  Am I missing some way to make this work?

```
="<a href=""" & "http://sharepoint/production/Library/Form " & CStr(Fields!FormNumber.Value) & ".gif"& """> test </a>"
```

^works fine

```
="<a href=""" & "http://sharepoint/production/Library/Form " & CStr(Fields!FormNumber.Value) & ".xml"& """> test </a>"
```

^doesn't appear

Comment: That was it.  The space was in the form name but for some reason either SSRS or the server refused to show it as an xml link when that space was there.  I changed them to underscores in infopath and links work fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update my issue here as it was more complicated then I thought.  Here's a [reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnissen/archive/2009/03/26/reporting-services-does-not-display-hyperlink-for-placeholder-with-go-to-url-action.aspx) to the issue.  It has nothing to with xml links or spacing.  It's actually working links that it fails to render, incorrect links to error pages work fine.  (confusing?  I know, right?)  The javascript solution didn't work for me b/c I need it to [work with Outlook 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885755).  What finally worked was reversing the slashes e.g.

```
 http:\\sharepoint
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

Drop the `space` between `...Form` and `&...`

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your xml url and in SSRS 2008R2 works fine (Can't test it in SSRS 2008). 
Maybe you should try to use Action->Go To Url instead of HTML murkup?